# How to pass list-view data to SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, mysql, listview

I'm building message app and my message and number are showing in list-view but I'm not sure how to pass the list-view data to SQLite database? This is my list view code looks like but not sure how to pass the data to database.

```
package com.example.sunny.messager;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class ListActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list);

        ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.SmsList);

        if(fetchInbox()!=null){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,fetchInbox());
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

    }
    public ArrayList<String> fetchInbox(){

        ArrayList<String> sms=new ArrayList<String>();

        Uri uriSms=Uri.parse("content://sms/");

        Cursor cursor=getContentResolver().query(uriSms, new String[]{"_id","address","date","body"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){

            String address=cursor.getString(1);
            String body=cursor.getString(3);

            sms.add("Number: " +address+"\n Message: " +body);
        }
        return sms;
    }
}
```

Comment: you probably mean a mysql database

Comment: yes it is mySQL database but I'm bit confused how to pass list view data to  the database automatically....any idea?...thanks

Comment: What do you want to pass to database? Number and message? In other words, how your table looks like in the database?

Comment: Yeah i just want to pass the Number and Message to mySQL and I want to create the database and table through my app so I'm guessing i need to use php script to pass that data? something like the code i just posted now? look up i added some php script.   thanks

Comment: Android has Sqlite built-in, and it appears you are trying to copy the device's sms messages into your own database? If you want to use Sqlite, I suggest you start by extending SQLiteOpenHelper:  [https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)

Comment: while writing the answer for you, I have one question: you want the table look like this Columns: id , number , message ??

Comment: Yes please, i tried to do that last night but the data from app to MySQL wasnt passing anything. thanks

Comment: Can i store datas in SQLite database? It is much easier than storing them in MySQL database. Is that Okey with you?

Comment: Yes SQLite databse is fine i guess. thanks

Comment: Edit your question from `MySQL` to `SQLite`.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but for some reason the SMSDatarepo showing errors for the `Student` , `number`, `message` , `studentList`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use these classes SQLiteDatabase and and SQLiteOpenHelper.

- **SQLiteDatabase** is the class for us to perform CRUD function.
- **SQLiteOpenHelper** is a helper class to manage database creation and version management.

Now let’s start code on table structure portion first – create table in Android. We will create a file name SMSData.java , and the code in this file will look like this

```
package com.example.sqlitedb;
public class SMSData {
    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE = "SMSData";

    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_number = "number";
    public static final String KEY_message= "message";

    // property help us to keep data
    public int SMSData_ID;
    public int number;
    public String message;
}
```

We’ll create a class and name it DBHelper.java and code in this file will look like this, to ease on understand code line by line i put comment in code.

```
package com.example.sqlitedb;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBHelper  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    //version number to upgrade database version
    //each time if you Add, Edit table, you need to change the
    //version number.
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "crud.db";

    public DBHelper(Context context ) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //All necessary tables you like to create will create here

        String CREATE_TABLE_SMSDATA= "CREATE TABLE " + SMSData.TABLE  + "("
                + SMSData.KEY_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,"
                + SMSData.KEY_number+ " INTEGER, "
                + SMSData.KEY_message+ " TEXT )";

        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SMSDATA);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed, all data will be gone!!!
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SMSData.TABLE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    } 

}
```

With above 2 steps, SMSData table will be created when app get started and now we could code the CRUD functions! Create SMSDataRepo.java, the purpose of this class is to perform CRUD on the SMSData table. The code in this file will look like this.

```
package com.example.sqlitedb;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class SMSDataRepo {
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public SMSDataRepo(Context context) {
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    }

    public int insert(SMSData sMSData) {

        //Open connection to write data
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(SMSData.KEY_number, sMSData.number);
        values.put(SMSData.KEY_message,sMSData.message);

        // Inserting Row
        long SMSData_Id = db.insert(SMSData.TABLE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        return (int) SMSData_Id;
    }

    public void delete(int SMSData_Id) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
        db.delete(SMSData.TABLE, SMSData.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(SMSData_Id) });
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void update(SMSData sMSData) {

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(SMSData.KEY_number, sMSData.number);
        values.put(SMSData.KEY_message,sMSData.message);

        // It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string
        db.update(SMSData.TABLE, values, SMSData.KEY_ID + "= ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(SMSData.SMSData_ID) });
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  getSMSDataList() {
        //Open connection to read only
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                SMSData.KEY_ID + "," +
                SMSData.KEY_number+                     
                SMSData.KEY_message+ "," +
                " FROM " + SMSData.TABLE;

        //SMSData sMSData= new SMSData();
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> sMSDataList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // looping through all rows and adding to list

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> sMSData= new HashMap<String, String>();
                sMSData.put("number", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_number)));
                sMSData.put("message", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_message)));
                sMSDataList.add(sMSData);

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return sMSDataList;

    }

    public SMSData getSMSDataById(int Id){
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        String selectQuery =  "SELECT  " +
                SMSData.KEY_ID + "," +
                SMSData.KEY_number + "," +
                SMSData.KEY_message +
                " FROM " + SMSData.TABLE
                + " WHERE " +
                SMSData.KEY_ID + "=?";// It's a good practice to use parameter ?, instead of concatenate string

        int iCount =0;
        SMSData sMSData= new SMSData();

        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, new String[] { String.valueOf(Id) } );

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                sMSData.SMSData_ID =cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_ID));
                sMSData.number=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_number));
                sMSData.message=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_message));

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return sMSData;
    }

}
```

Comment: @SrZues I have changed `SMSData` to `sMSData` in some places. See my answer now

Comment: @SrZues  I have also changed  `getString` to `getInt` like this `sMSData.number=cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(SMSData.KEY_number));`. I have edited my answer again :-)

Comment: Thanks it's not showing any error now. one more thing....is it possible to put them up online database?...i'm very new to SQLite but i want to have something like mySQL showing all sms data on database online....any idea?

Comment: @SrZues You didn't mention in the question that you want to store data on an online database. My code store all data locally, and the database will be created inside the device running the application.

Comment: I know but i'm just wondering if it's possible to do with SQLite?...i will need to have done offline and online database for my application

Comment: First of all, I guess you forgot to accept my answer :-) .Then, I will do some research and  will report it to you if it's possible to do it online.

Comment: Actually, you can upload the sqlite database to a webserver as a regular file, but with only backup intents this is plausible. For more informations, check this [link](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: is it possible doing through php script? and accept answer as in the green tick?

Comment: Answer accepted Thanks. I suggest you create a MySQL database on your webserver ( e.g wamp server ), then synchronise it with your SQLite database. This is [How to sync Remote MySQL DB to SQLite on Android?](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-sync-remote-mysql-db-to-sqlite-on-android/)

Comment: Thanks!... how i check if the my `listview` data are saving? ...i'm trying add delete and recover button but it's showing error  thanks

Comment: To test if your listView data is saved, you can first `insert(sMSData)` then check if the arrayList returned by `getSMSDataList()` is empty or not.

Comment: stupid question but you mean insert a message in my message box or i have to add `insert(sMSData)` somewhere in code?